# DotNetNuke - CS1056: Unexpected character '਍'

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

Have tried for the past few weeks for DNN to get an answer why this is happening - and get no reply.

On a brand new install of DNN7 on WinHost, When I try and add a new page I get the following error:

```
Error: is currently unavailable. DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.ModuleLoadException:         
e:\web\speedyto\DesktopModules\Admin\Tabs\ManageTabs.ascx.cs(2): 
error CS1056: Unexpected character '਍' ---> System.Web.HttpCompileException: 
e:\web\speedyto\DesktopModules\Admin\Tabs\ManageTabs.ascx.cs(2): error CS1056: Unexpected character '਍' at 
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath) at 
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) at 
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) at 
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) at 
System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.LoadControl(VirtualPath virtualPath) at 
DotNetNuke.UI.ControlUtilities.LoadControl[T](TemplateControl containerControl, String ControlSrc) at 
DotNetNuke.UI.Modules.WebFormsModuleControlFactory.CreateModuleControl(TemplateControl containerControl, ModuleInfo moduleConfiguration) at 
DotNetNuke.UI.Modules.ModuleControlFactory.LoadModuleControl(TemplateControl containerControl, ModuleInfo moduleConfiguration) at 
DotNetNuke.UI.Modules.ModuleHost.LoadModuleControl() --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

I was hoping someone might be able to point me in the right direction.

Comment: As seen on the DotNetNuke forums. It seems to be linked to the unzipping of the DotNetNuke installation files. I have never come across this problem. Have you tried the same installation on your local machine?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to install exactly similar version of the dotnetnuke in your local machine and try to regenerate problem. If it doesn't get regenerated, please overwrite `\DesktopModules\Admin\Tabs\ManageTabs.ascx.cs` file in your hosting copy.

I am sure this will help you to take some direction. If you can provide exact build version of dotnetnuke (current one is 07.00.04) I can suggest some more solutions.

- Prashant